# error mounting /dev/sdb1 at : unknown error when mounting /dev/sdb1

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive

error mounting /dev/sdb1 at: unknown error when mounting /dev/sdb1:

[image: error mounting /dev/sdb1 at: unknown error when mounting /dev/sdb1]

Comment: Where was the `/dev/sdb` last used? Windiws' "Fast boot" option leaves partitions unreadable by Linux.